# react router v6 - routing is not getting set correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to set private routing in my react app. I have created two components. ParivateRoute.js and ParivateRoute.js and I am importing these two components in App.js. I'm setting up private routing on tokens basis that if token is there then private routing is set and if token is null then public routing should be set.

I have tried some code with that my private routing is set but my public routing is not being set.

I am facing this problem in public routing that whenever both fields of login form(email & password) are empty and I am clicking on login button so path goes something like this `http://localhost:3000/?email=&password=`

While it should not be so. I want the path to be something like this `http://localhost:3000/` whenever I click on the login button and both my fields(email & password) are empty.

So for this I don't know how to get it. I want
help in getting routing path set correctly.

**One more help please**, I also want to set public routing on more than one component like Login as well as on SignUp. so how can I do that?

here is my code below.

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import RequireAuth from "./PrivateRoute";

const Login = ({ setTokenData }) => {
  const initialValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(initialValues);
  const authenticateUser = () => {
    const localInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signUpUser"));
    localInfo?.map((item) => {
      const userName = item.email;
      const userPassword = item.password;
      if (userName === userData.email && userPassword === userData.password) {
        console.log("success");
        const token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
        console.log("token is:", token);
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
        setTokenData(token);
        toUsersTable();
      } else {
        console.log("failure");
        return false;
      }
    });
    setUserData(initialValues);
  };

  const navigateToUsersTable = useNavigate();
  const toUsersTable = () => {
    return navigateToUsersTable("/usersTable");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form className="loginForm">
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            value={userData.email}
            name="email"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            value={userData.password}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox"></Form.Group>

        <Button
          variant="primary"
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => authenticateUser()}
        >
          Login
        </Button>

        <div className="txtToSignUpBtn">
          <span>OR</span> <Link to="/signUp">Click here to Register</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
      <RequireAuth authenticateUser={authenticateUser} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import UsersTable from "./UsersTable";

const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
  console.log("rest is", { ...rest });
  const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
  console.log(token);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route {...rest} element={token ? <UsersTable /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**PublicRoute.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";

const PublicRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
  const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        element={token ? <Navigate to="/usersTable" /> : <Login />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};
export default PublicRoute;
```

**App.js**

```
import { Layout } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
import UsersTable from "./UsersTable";
import PublicRoute from "./PublicRoute";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<SignUp />} exact path="/signUp" />
          </Routes>
          <PublicRoute element={<Login />} exact path="/" />
          <PrivateRoute element={<UsersTable />} exact path="/usersTable" />
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there are a few issues with your question that can make understanding difficult (two components both called the same file, asking multiple questions in the same question, etc.). That said, your code examples are very clear and helpful. I would suggest checking out [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e), as it might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Dykotomee, thanks for showing your interest. I also took help from the same Medium post to get done my code upto here.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` custom route components are out, replaced, or preferring wrapper components that handle the business logic and render either a `children` prop or an `Outlet` for nested routes, or the declarative redirect.

Since you asked about placing more than one component on a "private" route I suggest using the `Outlet` implementation.

```
const PrivateWrapper = () => {
  const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
  console.log(token);

  return token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const PublicWrapper = () => {
  const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));

  return token ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<div>Home Page</div>} />
            <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route element={<PublicWrapper />}>
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              .... other public routes ....
            </Route>
            <Route element={<PrivateWrapper />}>
              <Route path="/usersTable" element={<UsersTable />} />
              .... other private routes ....
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};
```

I don't see where you issue any imperative navigations including any queryString parameters but from what I can tell you aren't preventing the default form action when it's submitted. Move the submit handler to the `Form` component's `onSubmit` event handler and call `preventDefault` on the submit event object.

```
const authenticateUser = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
};

...

<Form className="loginForm" onSubmit={authenticateUser}>
  ...
  <Button
    variant="primary"
    type="submit"
  >
    Login
  </Button>
  ...
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the login button the url changes to `http://localhost:3000/?email=&password=` bcuz on yow form you did not specified the `method` it should use and the default value is a `GET`. it is why yow form inputs appear at the url, if you do not want to send them form fields in the url you need to set the method as post `method="POST"`. now them fields wont be send in the url, but as we is not in the 90's you dont have to do that. What you need to do is to prevent the default behavior.

remove from onClickHandler from the button and add it to the form

```
const onSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();
authenticateUser();
};

...
return(
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
...
 <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Login</Button>
```

but instead of been a onClick it is an onSubmit make sure to **preventDefault**